# Google-Plus sharing through javascript, with custom image

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-plus

I want to share some specific link to google plus thorugh javascript, at that time i got this method

```
window.open("https://plus.google.com/share?url=http://www.amazon.in/&t="+document.title, '', 'menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=300,width=600');
```

in a button onclick am using this code to execute. Here my question is when i tried to share this link its taking image for that link automatically but i want to customize the image of the link that i am sharing , how can i achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google+ gets properties from your webpage meta tags.The url gets from link/canonical.so if you want to set custom image for sharing,you need to change your meta tag.
For example

```
<meta property="og:image" content="image_path">
```

here is a link: http://www.w3docs.com/learn-javascript/google-share.html

Comment: Just followed the steps that they suggested but still its not taking custom image , here i am sharing the code , could you point out where i am missing it?<html>
  <head>
    <title>www.W3docs.com</title>
<meta property="og:image" content="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/432098859431374849/bffnqW_i_400x400.jpeg">
    <link rel="canonical" href="http://www.w3docs.com/" />
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <g:plus action="share"></g:plus>
  </body>
</html>

Comment: og:image must be whole path to the file.for example "http://www.w3docs.com/uploads/media/book_gallery/0001/01/066705b46be05dfdde77a1bc60c120b76257b553.png and the canonical link must be with http like
"http://www.w3docs.com/"

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Google+ shares take snippet info from the destination URL. The only way to change what image is selected by default is to [modify the markup](https://developers.google.com/+/web/snippet/) on the page.